# Controller not working after migrating to ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, owin

Im migrating my ASP.NET 4 app to ASP.NET Core.  Most methods in my API work fine, but strangely some don't and I cannot see any reason why.

I am using Owin.OAuth authentication (`OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`) and, for all but two calls, the `this.User` (from `ControllerBase`) property is populated correctly.  For two Controllers only this doesn't work!

So this controller works, more specifically at the point of construction this.User is none null and contains the correct user for their Bearer token.

```
[Authorize]
public class DriversController : AuthenticatedController
{
    public DriversController() : base()
    {
        // this.User is none null!
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/drivers")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDrivers()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

This controller does not work, when the constructor is hit, `this.User` is null

```
[Authorize]
public class DriversAssignmentController : AuthenticatedController
{
    public DriversAssignmentController() : base()
    {
        // this.User is null!
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/driverassignment")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDriversAssignments()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that `this.User` is a property on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` which `AuthenticatedController` inherits from.

Comment: Have you mixed up the Route attribute with the HttpGet attribute?

Comment: I initially decorated it with `[HttpGet]` and `[Route("api/...")]` and it didn't work.  I saw some examples that just used `HttpGet` so figured I'd try it.. it made no difference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `User` from the constructor, because it relies on the `ControllerContext` property, which is initialized by ASP.NET Core MVC after the constructor is invoked.

Ideally, consider refactoring your code so it doesn't try to access request-dependent properties like `User` from the constructor.

If you **really can't** refactor it, consider importing `IHttpContextAccessor` as a constructor dependency:

```
public DriversController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    var user = accessor.HttpContext.User;
}
```

Comment: So that would be why it doesnt work in the constructor but does in the methods!! Thanks for this.  I was using it in the constructor so I didnt have to repeat code to create my DataService layer on every call.